# Possibility to use custom `type` globally in golang

Tags: go

I have `type Number float64` in one of my package, and i want to use `Number` globally without specify the package name.

```
package a

type Number float64
```

---

```
package b

type data struct {
var1 a.Number
var2 a.Number
}
```

Instead of that i want to remove `a.`
is there any possibility?

Comment: No there isn't. You cannot declare anything as globally accessible. The only way to remove the `a.` is to import the package with a `.` in front of the `ImportPath`. e.g. `import . "a"`, this will then give the importing file direct access to `Number`.

Comment: what is the best practice for using custom type in package wide usage?

Comment: The idiomatic approach is to simply import the package into any file that needs to reference the type. And, by the way, the use of the `. ImportPath` imports mentioned in the previous comment is, if I remember correctly, recommended *against*.